# set Form Location Relevant to Parent Form Button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a MDI(Parent) Form and 2 other Forms. On form1 there is a button, location is (X:100, Y:200). I required when user click on the button through Form1, another form "Form2" should open. And location of Form2 should be right middle of the button(Sender).

I write this code

```
   Private Sub UpdateLocation(ByVal element As Control, ByVal frm As Form)
        Dim p As New Point(element.Location)
        p = element.PointToScreen(p)
        p.X = p.X + element.Width + 10
        p.Y = p.Y / 2

        Debug.Print(p.ToString)
        frm.Location = p
        frm.BringToFront()
    End Sub
```

but Form2 location is not as expected. 
In am calling the above function on button click event

```
    UpdateLocation(form1.button1, form2)
```

Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Output of the above code is:

[Button1_Click](http://goo.gl/yfbLS)

After a few tests I realized that point.x (location.x) is working, but not the point.y (location.y)

[You can download the piece of code from here](http://www.softnsolv.com/temp/FormLocation.zip). you can check the  actual issues with it.
VS2010 is required.

Comment: posting some screenshot would be helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: [Button1_Click] http://goo.gl/yfbLS
[Button2_Click] http://goo.gl/27wUM
[Button3_Click] http://goo.gl/yfbLS

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to account for the height of the button and the form if you want it in the middle:

```
Dim p As Point = Me.MdiParent.PointToScreen(element.Location)
p.X += element.Width + 10
p.Y += (element.Height / 2) - (frm.Height / 2)
```

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion is not working. to check the issues quickly, you can now download the code. pls check the main post.

Comment: @KartikGoyal Updated post.  In your case, use `Me.MdiParent.PointToScreen()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Private Sub UpdateLocation(ByVal element As Control, ByVal frm As Form)

        Dim p As New Point(element.Location)
        p = element.parent.PointToScreen(p)
        p.X = p.X + element.Width + 10
        p.Y = p.Y + (element.height/2)

        Debug.Print(p.ToString)
        frm.Location = p
        frm.BringToFront()

 End Sub
```

Comment: Here is what I came-up with the help of above 2 suggestions.
`Dim p As New Point(element.Location)
 p = element.Parent.PointToScreen(p)
 p.X = p.X + element.Width + 10
 p.Y += (element.Height / 2) - (frm.Height / 2)`
Above code is working with 1 MDI, 1 child and 1 normal form.
I will test this more with other cases and will post the results later.

Thanks LarsTech and Rajaprabhu Aravindasam, your suggestion was good enough.

Answer (score 0):

"Solved", Just to reconfirm

```
Private Sub UpdateLocation(ByVal element As Control, ByVal frm As Form)
        If IsNothing(element) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim p As New Point(element.Location)
        p = element.Parent.PointToScreen(p)
        p.X = p.X + element.Width + 5
        p.Y += (element.Height / 2) - (frm.Height / 2)

        frm.Location = p
        frm.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

this code is working 100% fine with all my cases.